# Magento 2 Remove Layout Option

Tags: magento2

I am creating a custom theme in Magento 2.
When selecting a the layout in the 'design' tab of a page, category, product etc I have options such as:

1. 1 column
2. 2 columns with left bar
3. 2 columns with right bar
4. 3 columns

I have figured out how to add my own layouts to this set of options.

My Question: How can I remove (or in a pinch - hide) the core layouts that are not required? My theme, for example, does not require a 3 column layout at all, and so I would not like this to be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's what you need to do:

Create a new `Module`: `app/code/<Vendor>/Cms`

You need to ensure the `Module` is registered correctly.

Then create the file: `app/code/<Vendor>/Cms/Model/PageLayout.php`

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\Cms\Model;

use Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\PageLayout as BasePageLayout;

class PageLayout extends BasePageLayout{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = parent::toOptionArray();
        $remove = [
            "empty",
            "1column",
            "2columns-left",
            "2columns-right",
            "3columns",
        ];

        foreach($options as $key => $layout){
            if(in_array($layout["value"], $remove)){
                unset($options[$key]);
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

This will get the `$options` and then remove any that are in the `$remove` array based on the `$option['value']`

In order to have this run, you need to override part of `app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml`

To do this create the file: `app/code/<Vendor>/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="design">
        <field name="page_layout">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object"><Vendor>\Cms\Model\PageLayout</item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

We are now telling that ui_component field to use our new Model to retrieve the options.

You can also create the file `app/code/<Vendor>/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="cms_page_columns">
        <column name="page_layout">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object"><Vendor>\Cms\Model\PageLayout</item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Apart from fact that this solution does not remove those default page layout options from some sections (like category or product design settings - but it is just a matter of updating adminhtml/ui_component layouts in this solution), this works properly. Therefore, I do not understand, why this answer is not marked as correct?